# Trouble getting <a> tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get a href attribute from <а> tag, but it doesn't work

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
print(a_tags[0].p) #print <p> tag
print(a_tags[0].a) #print 'None'
print(a_tags[0].a.get('href')) #doesn't work
```

but if I try to `print(a_tags)` it shows them:

```
[<a href="/org/colleges/instrcol/Pages/pic1.aspx" style="display:block;" target="_blank">
<div style="min-height:360px;">
<img alt="pic1" src="iblock/6ba/%d0%90%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%20%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%b9%20%d0%90%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87.jpg"/>
<p>Pic1</p></div>
</a>, <a href="/org/colleges/instrcol/Pages/pic2.aspx" style="display:block;" target="_blank">
<div style="min-height:360px;">
<img alt="pic2" src="iblock/1ee/%d0%90%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%20%d0%9f%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%20%d0%92%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87.jpg"/>
<p>Pic2</p></div>
</a>,
...
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: Why would an `a` tag have another `a` inside of it?

Comment: Did you try `a_tags[0].get('href')`?

Comment: I think I realized my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a_tags` contains `<a>` already.

Replace `a_tags[0].a.get('href')`  with `a_tags[0].get('href')`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `href=True` while using `find_all()`
Try this:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for a_tag in a_tags:
   print(a_tag['href'])
```